# Airflow on windows 10 - Module not found errors

Tags: environment-variables, airflow, pwd

I'm new to data science and wanted to do a [little tutorial](https://www.startdataengineering.com/post/data-engineering-project-for-beginners-batch-edition/), which requires airflow, among other things. I installed it on windows using git bash in VS Code. I tried running it but it had a problem not being able to load the sqlite3 import
command (module not found error). I figured out that if I added the directory of sqlite3.py to the path, it would run, but now it gives me a similar error: pwd module not found from daemon.py

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\daemon\daemon.py", line 18, in <module>
    import pwd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwd'
```

Strange to me that it can't find pwd. Obviously pwd works in both git bash and powershell natively. It seems like a basic universal command. I'd love to learn more about what's going on. I don't want to have to end up adding 100 things to path just to get this program to run. I'd love any insights anyone can provide.

PS I'm using Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

it's seems to be the side effects of  [Spawning new Python Daemons](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8674) .
You likely can fix this by downgrading the Python-Daemon :

```sh
 pip install python-daemon==2.1.2
```